# Coroutine scope cancel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I know that there are a lot of posts "**How to cancel Coroutines Scope**" but I couldn't find the answer for my case.
I have an `Array` of `objects` that I want to send each of them to **Server** using **Coroutines**.

What I need is, if one of my requests returns error, canceling others.

Here is my code:

```
    private fun sendDataToServer(function: () -> Unit) {
        LiabilitiesWizardSessionManager.getLiabilityAddedDocuments().let { documents ->
            if (documents.isEmpty().not()) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    documents.mapIndexed { index, docDetail ->
                        async {
                            val result = uploadFiles(docDetail)
                        }
                    }.map {
                        var result = it.await()

                    }
                }

            } else function.invoke()
        }
    }
```

Below is my uploadFiles() function:

```
        private suspend fun uploadFiles(docDetail: DocDetail): ArchiveFileResponse? {
    LiabilitiesWizardSessionManager.mCreateLiabilityModel.let { model ->
        val file = File(docDetail.fullFilePath)
        val crmCode = docDetail.docTypeCode
        val desc = docDetail.docTypeDesc
        val id = model.commitmentMember?.id
        val idType = 1
        val createArchiveFileModel = CreateArchiveFileModel(108, desc, id, idType).apply {
            this.isLiability = true
            this.adaSystem = 3
        }

        val result = mRepositoryControllerKotlin.uploadFile(file, createArchiveFileModel)
        return when (result) {
            is ResultWrapper.Success -> {
                result.value
            }
            is ResultWrapper.GenericError -> {
                null
            }
            is ResultWrapper.NetworkError -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know, I'm missing something.

Comment: I would say what you're missing is an extra layer. The code to upload "one" file should return "success/failure". The code to upload a list of files, should do whatever it needs to send one, wait, if it's success continue, if it fails, stop. You're trying to solve two problems "in a single class/method".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If I get you right, I should move the result handling to uploadFiles() function, and return only success/failure?

Comment: That's how I would do it, yes. If the code to upload "a file" is simple, understandable, reusable, and testable, then you can separate the responsibility of your use-case of "uploading a list of N items". It would make it easier if, for instance, you later realize you want to upload 5 at the time (instead of 1), and any other thing you can think of. Instead of adding more spaghetti to a code that should be simple (upload something). It's an opinion though... that's what I would *try* to do.

Comment: @Martin Marconcini
I Update the question with the new code, hope it's what you meant for.
But the main question is, how do I canceling the scope if one of them, return null?

Comment: `mRepositoryControllerKotlin.uploadFile` -- is this a suspendable function? If yes,  then you don't need `Dispatchers.IO`, it can safely run on the `Main`. And if it isn't, then your `uploadFiles` shouldn't be suspendable either, because it contains blocking code.

Comment: As for cancelling, just throw an exception from the `async` where you detect the error. This will propagate into cancelling all the other ones, as per structured concurrency. You're using an ad-hoc coroutine scope that you can't cancel from the outside, but you didn't ask for that.

Comment: MartinMarconcini
MarkoTopolnik 
Thank you guys for your answers.